# How to return json from callback function within the Lambda?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to return the login status from the Cognito callback function, which is written in the NodeJS Lambda. However when I call the API the response keep loading and I'm getting warning error.

**Here is my code:**

```
'use strict';

global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: "Hello there"
    }),
  };

  // Use this code if you don't use the http event with the LAMBDA-PROXY integration
  // return { message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event };
};


module.exports.register = async (event, context, callback) => {

  let poolData =  {
      UserPoolId : 'xxxxx', // Your user pool id here
      ClientId : 'xxxxxxx' // Your client id here
  } // the user Pool Data

  let userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

  let attributeList = [];

  let dataEmail = {
      Name : 'email',
      Value : 'test@gmail.com'
  };

  let dataName = {
      Name : 'name',
      Value : 'Jack'
  };

  var dataPhoneNumber = {
      Name : 'phone_number',
      Value : '+94234324324234' // your phone number here with +country code and no delimiters in front
  };

  let attributeEmail = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
  let attributeName = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataName);
  var attributePhoneNumber = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPhoneNumber);

  attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
  attributeList.push(attributeName);
  attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);

  userPool.signUp('test@gmail.com', 'H1%23$4jsk', attributeList, null, function(err, result){

    let data = {};

    if (err) {
      callback(null, {
          statusCode: 500,
          body: JSON.stringify({
            status: 'FAIL',
            message: err.message
          }),
        });
      } else {
        let cognitoUser = result.user;

        callback(null, {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify({
            status: 'SUCCESS',
            message: '',
            data: {
              username: cognitoUser.getUsername(),
              id: result.userSub
            }
          }),
        });
      }
  })

  // Use this code if you don't use the http event with the LAMBDA-PROXY integration
  // return { message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event };
};
```

**The warning error as follows:**

```
Serverless: Warning: handler 'register' returned a promise and also uses a callback!
This is problematic and might cause issues in your lambda.

Serverless: Warning: context.done called twice within handler 'register'!
```

**serverless.yml**

```
service: test-auth 
plugins:
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: message
          method: get
  register:
    handler: handler.register  
    events:
      - http:
          path: register
          method: post
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

EDIT (2019-04-01):

```
module.exports.register = (event, context) => {

  ...

  userPool.signUp('test@gmail.com', 'H1%23$4jsk', attributeList, null, function(err, result){

    // for testing purpose directly returning 
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        status: 'FAIL',
        message: err.message
      })
    }

  })

};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the error is accurate. `async` wraps your `return` with `promise`. Either use callback all the way through like:

```
global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

// remove async
module.exports.register = (event, context, callback) => {

  ...

  // if you're using callback, don't use return (setup your callback to be able to handle this value as required) instead do:
  // calback({ message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event })

  // Use this code if you don't use the http event with the LAMBDA-PROXY integration
  // return { message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event };
};
```

Or don't use callback, use `async/await` (`Promise`) all the way through like:

```
module.exports.register = async (event, context) => {

  ...

  // needs promise wrapper, when using with promise, you might want to break up your code to be more modular
  const mySignUp = (email, password, attributes, someparam) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      userPool.signUp(email, password, attributes, someparam, function(err, result) {

        let data = {};

        if (err) {
          reject({
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
              status: 'FAIL',
              message: err.message
            }),
          });
        } else {
          let cognitoUser = result.user;

          resolve({
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
              status: 'SUCCESS',
              message: '',
              data: {
                username: cognitoUser.getUsername(),
                id: result.userSub
              }
            }),
          });
        }
      })
    });
  }

  // call the wrapper and return
  return await mySignUp('test@gmail.com', 'H1%23$4jsk', attributeList, null);

  // don't use double return
  // Use this code if you don't use the http event with the LAMBDA-PROXY integration
  // return { message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event };
};
```

Now `register` will return a `promise`. Elsewhere in your code you can call register like:

```
var result = register();
result
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  // catches the reject from Promise
  .catch(err => console.error(err))

or in async/await function (Note: `await` is valid only inside `async` function)

async function someFunc() {
  try {
    var result = await register();
    // do something with result
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
  // reject from Promise
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

Also note `use strict` is not required here as node modules use strict by default.

Comment: Thanks for the detail reply, however when I just return I'm getting timeout error `[Serverless-Offline] Your λ handler 'register' timed out after 30000ms.` I even tried increasing the timeout value in the YML file but sill no use (See my EDIT code ). when I tried the callback it just print the message in the command line. I just want to output the JSON response after the success of the callback function. The promise example you demonstrated working fine, however since it's blocking I don't want to use it. Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `await` is `blocking` as it pauses execution. If you don't want blocking then use the `then` callback for promise like `somePromise.then(/*you can pass your callback function here*/() => //do something)`

Answer (score 6):

Its exactly what the error message states.

All `async` functions return promises.
`module.exports.register = async (event, context, callback) => {}`

You are also using the callback by calling

```
callback(null, {
          statusCode: 500,
          body: JSON.stringify({
            status: 'FAIL',
            message: err.message
          }),
        });
```

Instead of using the callback, just return the either an error or a valid response.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, after I removed the async I'm not getting any warning. However, it's also does not return anything if just return it. I'm now getting `[Serverless-Offline] Your λ handler 'register' timed out after 30000ms.` I even tried increasing the timeout value in the YML file but sill no use. Any what causing the error?

Comment: I'm still learning Node so please excuse my nube question.  Isn't the first parameter in a callback supposed to be used for errors?  In your example the first callback param is null and then the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an async function with a call back.

Try it this way:

Remove the callback from the async function.

`async (event, context)`

And modify the return as:

```
if (err) {
      return {
          statusCode: 500,
          body: JSON.stringify({
            status: 'FAIL',
            message: err.message
          })
        }
      }
```

And put an `await` on the function call.

Comment: Tried, still I'm getting the warning message and does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else catching this, you can add headers to the return:

```js
return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify(response.data)
    };
```